# How to make gRPC client (c++) to follow DNS TTL to refresh the IP address of AWS ELB load balancer?

Tags: c++, dns, grpc, amazon-elb, ttl

AWS ELB load balancer would change its IP addresses frequently while its DNS name has the TTL set to 60 seconds. It looks like gRPC wouldn't be able to refresh the IP address of an AWS ELB load balancer until a connection with the old IP address fails.

I'm using gRPC 1.15.1 (c++). Would there be a way to make gRPC client (c++) to follow DNS TTL to refresh the IP address of AWS ELB load balancer?

Comment: `GRPC_ARG_DNS_MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_RESOLUTIONS_MS` might help, but I'm not sure how it behaves after a successful resolution.

Comment: Thanks. But GRPC_ARG_DNS_MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_RESOLUTIONS_MS is to set the minimum amount of time between DNS resolutions to avoid overwhelming resolutions. I need the other way round more or less.

Comment: Right, but since the default value appears to be 30 seconds, explicitely setting it to a lower value might help (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/feb721c9a977a4ab5638a5942b1ccfc04459db41/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.cc#L158)

Comment: Found a solution. Just recreate a new stub for new gRPC quest if the existing stub is idle more than the DNS TTL since the IP may not be available anymore.